# Telegram get update from php

Tags: php, bots

I'm trying to write a new bot for telegram.
I wrote a php file with simple code, that gets updates:

```
<?php
$botToken = mytoken;
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
$update = file_get_contents($website."/getupdates");
print_r($update);
?>
```

I uploaded it on my website, but using the browser, when I try to access the file, I have no answer (the page is and remain black).

What's wrong?
Does webhook must be enabled?

Comment: The syntax is correct. what is the error of `file_get_contents`?

Comment: No. setting webhook disable `getupdates` and require a site with SSL enabled.

Comment: How do I get error from "file_get_contents" @fusion3k

Comment: 1) search on apache error logfile. 2) start your php script (after `<?php`) with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

Comment: Where's apache error logfile? @fusion3k

Comment: What OS you are using and which Webserver?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Telegram Update</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $bottoken = 'xxx0856284xxx';
    $update=file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$bottoken.'/getUpdates');
    print_r($update);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

// It works for me with XAMPP in C:\xampp\htdocs folder on: http://localhost/test.php
and it also works on domain in live